# How to query all fields individually with ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

As I understand it, ElasticSearch searches on the magic _all field by default. The problem with this seems to be that if a field uses a different index analyzer, the analyzed data from this field is not searched.

I've had success with searching on the fields ['domain', '_all'] but I really need to avoid having to manually specify each field which was analyzed differently. I see fields supports wildcards but seemingly not '*' on its own. I could do a*, b*, c*, d* etc. but this seems a tad inefficient.

Comment: Can you post your mapping & your query to gist ? It will help to investigate the problem more easy. It may be a problem in the analyzer , not the "_all" field

Comment: Thanks - https://gist.github.com/phil-lavin/7784696

Comment: I can successfully query _all without any problem, here is the full test shell script: https://gist.github.com/tintin04/7820194, you can index more data to check. I'm using ES 0.90.5

Comment: That's presumably because the 'armschel.com' string gets tokenized as 'armschel' and 'com' with the standard tokenizer. Here's an example closer to the real world that demonstrates the issue https://gist.github.com/phil-lavin/7874136. Changing the search query to be "domains:armschel" produces matches.

Comment: yes "armschel.com" will be indexed as "armschel", "com", and you use query_string with default operator (OR), so the query for "armschel.com" will become "armschel" OR "com", and it will match documents that contains "armschel", or "com", or both

Comment: The point here is that a search on _all for 'armschel' does not match thekingsarmschelsea.com whereas a search on domains for 'armschel' does. My original question is... how can I search on all fields without specifying each one individually?

Comment: I see, the data was tokenized correctly, but the field still not take into account for searching. It's more like a bug, afraid that you have to specify field name, or at least a*, b*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the special field "_all" is discontinued and copy_to function can be used instead as per the official [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/copy-to.html). This approach allows one to create a computed field (managed by elastic search) that one can specify to copy data from other fields to mimic _all search.

However there is an alternative approach through the use of multi_match providing wildcard field names as part of the query. This works just like the earlier mechanism searching "_all" field.

```
{"multi_match":{"query":"java","fields":["*"]}}]}}
```